# Subtracting multiple numbers

Tags: java, oop, methods, subtraction

I am trying to write a method that will subtract multiple numbers instead of using just 2 input numbers.

So far I have...

```
public void getSub() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the number: ");
        double value = in.nextDouble();
        double difference = 0;

        while(in.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the next number: ");
            double valueTwo = in.nextInt();
            difference = value - valueTwo;
        }
        System.out.println("Difference: " + difference);
    }
```

this currently only works with 2 inputs,  but my end goal is to be able to continue subtracting multiple numbers.

Comment: Why are you checking to see if there's a next `double`, but then reading an `int`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @CPerkins I'm guessing the question is why it isn't working how the creator hoped it would work

Comment: @phflack he doesn't say *what* is wrong.  He doesn't say in what way it's differing.   I'm not going to read his mind, and neither should we.  I tried asking for clarity, got none, I'm now voting to close.

Comment: @CPerkins I agree that it is poorly worded, which is why we must guess the most generic thing possible to be correct in guessing.  All we know is that it probably doesn't work the way OP wants it to, but we don't know what the desired end result may be

Comment: @phflack Guessing is a bad practice in programming.   If you agree it's poorly worded, you should want to get clarity or close the question.

Comment: @CPerkins which is why I use the most generic thing possible, to be correct in any possible case.  Very similar to class inheritance.  And I'm not disagreeing about any of it

Comment: is this question solved? then choose the answer please. If not let us know about the problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of continually subtracting from `value`, instead subtract from `difference`

Change `difference = value - valueTwo;` to `difference -= valueTwo`

This will be equivalent to doing `((A - B) - C) - ...`, A being the first input, B the second input, C the third input...

Comment: In case it isn't clear ``difference -= valueTwo`` is shorthand for "subtract ``valueTwo`` from ``difference`` and assign the result to ``difference``.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getSub() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the number: ");

    double difference = in.nextDouble();

    while(in.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.print("Please enter the next number: ");
        difference -= in.nextDouble();
    }
    System.out.println("Difference: " + difference);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***This should work fine***

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int result=0, n,number,i;
    printf("How many numbers you want to use?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d", &number);
        if(i ==0 ){
            result=number;
        }
        else{
            result -= number;
        }
    }
    printf("Answer is= %d ", result);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
How many numbers you want to use?                                                       
4  
                                                                                     
55                                                                                      
34                                                                                      
1                                                                                       
3                                                                                       
Answer is= 17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void compute_Substraction() {
        Scanner myinputs = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter value one ");
        double value =myinputs.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter  remaining number of values you desire 

           to use");
        int num = myinputs.nextInt();
              for (int i = 1; i <=num; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter num " + (i+1));
                double thevalue = myinputs.nextDouble();
                value -=thevalue;
           }
        System.out.println("The final value is " + value);
    }
// Answer is as below
Enter value one 
20
Enter  remaining number of values you desire to use
1
Enter num 2
6
The final value is 14.0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This solution doesn't hang after the first input. It is more user friendly.

```
public static void getSub() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the next number: ");
        double difference = 0.0;
        while(in.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the next number: ");
            difference -= in.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println("Difference: " + difference);
    }
```

Comment: You're printing out `Please enter the next number: ` twice on the first entry, you should use the first printout to prompt the user to input a value to initialize `difference`

Answer (score -1):

Why have two variables? Anyway, the following is simpler and prompts correctly:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter the number: ");
double value = in.nextDouble();
while (true) {
    in.nextLine(); // Silently discard rest of line
    System.out.print("Please enter the next number, or . to stop: ");
    if (! in.hasNextDouble())
        break;
    value -= in.nextDouble();
}
System.out.println("Difference: " + value);
```

*Test*

```
Please enter the number: 10
Please enter the next number, or . to stop: 1
Please enter the next number, or . to stop: 2
Please enter the next number, or . to stop: 3
Please enter the next number, or . to stop: .
Difference: 4.0
```